# What is the asymptotic growth of $\sum_{k=1}^n 2^{\omega_k}$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, gr.group-theory, analytic-number-theory

> **Question**: Let $\omega_k$ be the number of distinct prime divisors of k.
>   What is the asymptotic growth of $C_n := \sum_{k=1}^n 2^{\omega_k}$?

Thank you for considering this elementary question. Below I give some motivation for this problem and some of my progress.

**Motivation:**
There are a couple. The first is purely number theoretic. Note that because $2^{\omega_k} = \sum_{d | k} |\mu(d)|$, we have $C_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{d|k} |\mu(d)|,$ and thus $C_n$ is the asymptotic growth of absolute values of the  Möbius function (in other contexts this relates to the Prime Number Theorem, see [here](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/08/30/an-elementary-inequality-involving-the-mobius-function/)).

The second motivation comes from geometric group theory. The *commensurability index* of $A, B \leq G$ (all groups) is $[A : A \cap B][B: A \cap B]$. The *full commensurability growth function* assigned to a pair $A \leq B$ is defined to be 
$$
C_n(A,B) = \# \{ \Delta \leq B : c(\Delta, A) \leq n \}.
$$
This is a generalization of the [subgroup growth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgroup_growth) function to pairs and it can be infinite in natural settings. The question above is the case $G(\mathbb{Z}) = \mathbb{Z} \leq \mathbb{R} = G(\mathbb{R})$ of the following

> **Problem:** Compute the full commensurability growth function for the pairs $G(\mathbb{Z}) \leq G(\mathbb{R})$ where $G$ is a unipotent linear algebraic group.

**Some progress:**
Write $f \preceq g$ if there exists $C > 0$ such that $f(n) \leq C g(C n)$. 
In [Proposition .3](https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.10332), it is shown that $n (\log(n))^{\log(2)} \leq C_n \preceq n(\log(n))$.

Comment: This is [A064608](https://oeis.org/A064608)

Comment: Thank you user:41291 (forgive me I don’t know how to write your name).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As you observe,
$$C_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{d\mid k}|\mu(d)|=\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{d\mid k\text{ squarefree}}1.$$
Exchanging the order of summation,
$$C_n=\sum_{d\leq n\text{ squarefree}}\sum_{d\mid k\leq n}1=\sum_{d\leq n\text{ squarefree}}\left\lfloor\frac{n}{d}\right\rfloor=n\sum_{d\leq n\text{ squarefree}}\frac{1}{d}+O(n).$$
Now, the squarefree numbers have density $\frac{1}{\zeta(2)}=\frac{6}{\pi^2}$, so by summation by parts it's easy to find $\sum_{d\leq n\text{ squarefree}}\frac{1}{d}\sim\frac{1}{\zeta(2)}\log n$, hence giving $C_n\sim\frac{1}{\zeta(2)}n\log n$. You should be able to get an $O(n)$ bound on the error this way, and using the hyperbola method you should get some more precise estimates.

Comment: [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A064608) also mentions Merten's theorem (1874): $\frac n{\zeta(2)}\left(\log n + 2\gamma - 1 - 2\frac{\zeta'(2)}{\zeta(2)}\right) + O(\sqrt n\log n)$

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I was so close ...

Comment: Alternatively, break the sum up into k subsums and count the numbers less than n with k distinct prime factors.  Landau did this, with a logarithmically shrinking numerator and (k-1)! in the denominator, so one can get a good approximation with about k=loglog n many terms.  Gerhard "Go Where The Mass Is" Paseman, 2018.09.28.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman: one needs to be careful with heuristics here, because $2^x$ grows so fast that the relatively few integers with substantially more than $\log\log n$ prime factors contribute more to the sum of $2^{\omega(n)}$ than the density-1 set of integers with around $\log\log n$ prime factors. (Note that the contribution of the latter is about $x\cdot 2^{\log\log x} = x(\log x)^{\log 2}$, which is less than the main term for the sum.) The same thing happens with the divisor function: most of the mass in the sum comes from integers with about $\frac1{\log2}\log\log x$ prime factors.

Comment: @Greg, what do you think would be a good cutoff for this sum then? (k=(loglog x)^2), maybe?  Gerhard "Is Willing To Add More" Paseman, 2018.09.28.